# Flash buttons working on every platform, except Safari

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, safari, osx-leopard

Basically, every button works in Firefox, Chrome, IE, but they will not work in Safari.

I'm using straightforward code:

```
Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonClick);
function ButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void  {
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

The movie starts on frame 2 - frame 1 is a preloader. Classes are set to start on frame 2, but changing that to frame 1 didn't do anything either.

I'm at a loss here. Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the right symbols by using Button1 ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to learn how to format your code so that it's easier for us to read

```
 Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonClick); 

 function ButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
 { 
     gotoAndStop(3); 
  }
```

Next, is to make sure you're using the last updates both for your browsers and FlashPlayer

Finally, try to add trace() statements in order to find out where the application breaks.

```
 Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonClick);
 trace("Button instance " , Button1); 

 function ButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
 { 
     gotoAndStop(3); 
    trace(event); 
  }
```

When debugging both in Firefox & Safari , for instance, it may give you some clues and probably help you make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if you've already tried this but see if changing the "wmode" attribute of the object/embed tags makes a difference. I had issues with having it set to "transparent", in Safari, once upon a time.